# Detect if apt-get update is necessary

Tags: linux, debian, apt, aptitude

Is there a way to detect if running `apt-get update` is necessary?

It seems that whenever `apt-get update` is run, it downloads the latest lists even if I already have them, and I want to avoid downloading lists if I already have the latest ones.

Comment: How did you get the latest lists?

Comment: By `apt-get update`. My point is that if I run it twice, it downloads the lists twice.

Comment: What version of Linux? On my Ubuntu System, Ubuntu looks after it with its own updater. On Kali (from Root) I run apt update and then follow it with apt upgrade. That completes it all

Comment: Debian 10 Buster, Linux 4.19.97

Comment: Kali is based on Debian. Run Upgrade after Update to complete it all

Comment: Nods, I know. But `apt-get update` downloads package lists, and before I run it I want to know if I need to run it (I wouldn't need to run it if my package lists are up-to-date, like if no package lists were changed between the time I ran it and the time I ran it last)

Comment: I think you'll have to iterate over all URLs in your sources and check the time stamps on the far repo per file against the mtime of all local files  ... the checks might actually take longer than just downloading them again. At least on my connection.

Comment: Thankyou @tink, I guess it's better just to download them again. If you post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the URLs from all sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` and compare the file's timestamps in the respective remote repos against the `ctimes` of your files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` ... but that would IMHO take longer than just downloading those again (at least on my connection the 50MB are dealt with very quickly).

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is not correct: `apt update` does not fetch catalogue files which it already has downloaded at the up-to-date versions; let's see:

1. The first run of `apt update`:

   ```
   …
   Get:33 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,683 kB]                              
   Get:34 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,474 kB]                              
   Fetched 16.1 MB in 4s (4,496 kB/s)                                                                 
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   64 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
   ```

   As you can see, `apt` indeed fetched 16.1 MiB worth of data.
2. The second run:

   ```
   Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
   Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                           
   Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                   
   Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid InRelease       
   Reading package lists... Done                          
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   64 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
   ```

   As you can see, no data were fetched.

"The trick" here is that when `apt` makes an HTTP[S] request to an archive server, it includes in it the "last modified" time of each resource it has alredy cached; the server looks at that timestamp, and if it does not have a version of that resource which is fresher, it responds with a special HTTP status code ("not modified") and no body. `apt` notices that and uses what's already available right away.

As you can see, there is still *some* traffic (outgoing requests and incoming responses to them) but:

- It's miniscule compared to that when the data is fetched.
- You simply can't be sure the archive have no updated data without performing a check.